# How to handle Retry and Added entities in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

My project already has a retry and transaction policy defined. I'm having trouble with the current workflow:

1. Initiate a transaction with a retry policy
2. Query for my `Foo` entity, if it does not exists, insert in the context
3. Run other operations that failed due to a due to a transient transaction

When the retry policy takes place and runs step 2 again, the query doesn't return the previously added entity, but it is in `context.ChangeTracker.Entries()` as `Added`. The step 2 added another entity and I end up with a `RepositoryDuplicateKeyException`.

Is there any better way to include the added entity in the query or do I have to manually check for the entities in the `ChangeTracker`?

Currently, I'm ignoring the `RepositoryDuplicateKeyException` which seems pretty hacky too.

Comment: What database type (MS SQL Server, Postgres, etc) are you working with?

Comment: Can you show some of your code?

Comment: Sorry, SQL Server.

Comment: The code is all spread across the application and wrapped in helper classes.